# Fastest way to start an application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In my application the start time is critical - I need it to be as small as possible. If the application starts from home screen (user clicks the icon) the start time is acceptable (less than one second) but if I start my application from a service - I have a service that starts/focus my application based on some events - the start time is more than one second.

The code that starts my application is this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AppActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION );
startActivity(i);
```

Is there any way to improve the start time? Sometimes (most of the time) my application is running and the code above only put my app on foreground (no need to start, only to "focus"). The time - as I see it - doesn't change if the app starts or just get focus.

How do I improve the start/focus time?

Comment: Not a solution you want i guess, but you may decrease the run-time complexity at onCreate(). Thus application may provide user interface as soon as possible. The details may be constructed via another thread.

Comment: You can try with flag CLEAR_TOP, this will bring up an existing instance if there is one, do you need to flat it with new task?

Comment: Now my flags are like this: i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION );

Comment: But no change in start time. Regarding the onCreate method... it's almost empty, just load 6 controls defined in xml. I cannot make it smaller.